Creating an outliner and a summariser to register a language
I am trying to update the registering of my language and with the new specifications I need to define an Outliner and a Summariser
Here is the example project for the pico dsl file here and the language specification (i assume) here
module lang::pico::LanguageServer

import util::LanguageServer;
import util::IDEServices;
import ParseTree;
import util::Reflective;
import lang::pico::\syntax::Main;
import IO;

// a minimal implementation of a DSL in rascal
// users can add support for more advanced features
set[LanguageService] picoContributions() = {
    parser(parser(#start[Program])), // register the parser function for the Pico language
    outliner(picoOutliner),
    summarizer(picoSummarizer, providesImplementations = false)
  };


// we build a simple outline based on the grammar
list[DocumentSymbol] picoOutliner(start[Program] input)
  = [symbol("<input.src>", DocumentSymbolKind::\file(), input.src, children=[
      *[symbol("<var.id>", \variable(), var.src) | /IdType var := input]
  ])];

// normally you would import the typechecker and run it here
// for brevity we've inlined the implementation here
Summary picoSummarizer(loc l, start[Program] input) {
    rel[str, loc] defs = {<"<var.id>", var.src> | /IdType var  := input};
    rel[loc, str] uses = {<id.src, "<id>"> | /Id id := input};
    rel[loc, str] docs = {<var.src, "*variable* <var>"> | /IdType var := input};


    return summary(l,
        messages = {<src, error("<id> is not defined", src)> | <src, id> <- uses, id notin defs<0>},
        references = (uses o defs)<1,0>,
        definitions = uses o defs,
        documentation = (uses o defs) o docs
    );
}

// run this from a REPL while developing the DSL
int main() {
    // we register a new language to Rascal's LSP multiplexer
    // the multiplexer starts a new evaluator and loads this module and function
    registerLanguage(
        language(
            pathConfig(srcs=[|project://pico-dsl-lsp/src/main/rascal|]),
            "Pico", // name of the language
            "pico", // extension
            "lang::pico::LanguageServer", // module to import
            "picoContributions"
        )
    );
    return 0;
}

I am trying to build both an Outliner and a Summarizer for my language (AST here).
data Pipeline
    = pipeline(
    Alphabet alphabet,
    Options options,
    list[Module] modules,
    list[Constraint] constraints,
    list[Handler] handlers
    );
 
data Alphabet
    = alphabet(
    list[SymbolInfo] symbols);

Here is what I have for the outliner so far, I cant find further documentation on their structure:
list[DocumentSymbol] ldOutliner(start[Pipeline] pipeline) {
    return [
        symbol("Pipeline", DocumentSymbolKind::Namespace, pipeline.src, children=[
            *[symbol("Alphabet"
            
                {...}
            ]
        ])
    ];
}

Additionally, the contributions style were defined as following, how can i define the style now?
Contribution STYLE =
  categories
  (
    (
      "Name" : {bold()},
      "String" : {foregroundColor(color("purple"))},
      "Boolean" : {foregroundColor(color("DarkRed"))},
      "ColorCode" : {foregroundColor(color("Violet"))},
      "Character" :{foregroundColor(color("dimgray"))},
      "ConstraintKeywords" :{foregroundColor(color("Olive"))},
      "Integer" : {foregroundColor(color("orange")), bold()}
    )
    );

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Hi  some things have changed between VScode and eclipse. I'll try an clarify a.s.a.p.


the new outliner is missing () for the DocumentSymbolKind constructor. That makes it a reference to the function instead of an instance of the datatype. It could be that this error is printed in a different view than where you are looking! It should be DocumentSymbolKind::Namespace()
The LSP outline is much more limited than what we had in Eclipse, on the other hand all outlines now look the same and behave the same for usability's sake.
We lost the ability to define our own syntax categories too, going from eclipse IMP to VScode, however, now theming works nicely and you'll have a darkmode DSL for free  It means the contribution for registering categories simply does not exist anymore.

